# How to use ServiceRegistry

Tags: java

I run into a problem, I wrote a `Class(EasybImpl)` which implement `EasybPlugin`, but when I iterate providers, I could not get the EasybImpl support that i wrote.

I thought the EasybImpl is using the System classloader and the console println the classloader as sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader. what's wrong with it.

```
    Iterator providers = ServiceRegistry.lookupProviders(EasybPlugin.class, 
                         ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you declare your class as a service provider?

> To declare a service provider, a services subdirectory is placed within the META-INF directory that is present in every JAR file. This directory contains a file for each service provider interface that has one or more implementation classes present in the JAR file. For example, if the JAR file contained a class named com.mycompany.mypkg.MyServiceImpl which implements the javax.someapi.SomeService interface, the JAR file would contain a file named:
>
> META-INF/services/javax.someapi.SomeService
>
> containing the line:
>
> com.mycompany.mypkg.MyService

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/spi/ServiceRegistry.html

Answer (score 0):

Four steps are required:

- you build a META-INF/services subdirectory into your JAR file.
- in the 'services' directory, create a file for each service you are implementing. (in your case, this would be file `META-INFA/services/my.package.EasybPlugin`).
- in that file, declare the name of your implementation class(es).
- you can then use the `java.util.ServiceLoader` API to discover & load registered services.

An example of the service provider file:

```
# providers of EasyBPlugin SPI
# (comment lines begin with pound)
my.package.StandardEasybPlugin
```

You can then find and load service implementations like this:

```
ServiceLoader<EasybPlugin> loader = ServiceLoader.load(EasybPlugin.class);
for (EasybPlugin plugin : loader) {
    // ...
}
```

Note 1: the `ServiceProvider` API you were looking at is really targetted at Image IO, eg reading image file formats. `ServiceLoader` is for general use & should be preferred unless your purpose is not reading images.

There's a more detailed tutorial here:  http://literatejava.com/extensibility/java-serviceloader-extensible-applications/

References:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html#the-serviceloader-class
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/SPI-intro.html  *targetted at sound, but clear simple examples of the service provider files*.